# AD FS 2.0 with PingIdentity / AppFabric Labs ACS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wif, pingfederate

Could be a simple question, I'm just looking really for someone that has implemented this. I've got AppFabric Labs v2 currently working with an AD FS 2.0 server with Active Directory, that's all fine and then this links to AppFabric, and routes round to my .NET app (relying party).

My question is simple - how do I get PingIdentity to work with AppFabric and come up as an STS provider? I've tried importing the .XML meta data from the PingIdentity admin system with no joy.

Is the common route for people to attach their AD FS 2.0 server to AppFabric and then attach PingIdentity to their AD FS 2.0 server as a claims provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened when you imported the metadata into ACS? Can you provide more details of what's not working?

Regarding:

> Is the common route for people to
>   attach their AD FS 2.0 server to
>   AppFabric and then attach PingIdentity
>   to their AD FS 2.0 server as a claims
>   provider?

Either way could work. ACS is still "labs" so not many production systems have gone live, so in terms of actual cases, you will find more ADFS<->Ping. But, again, either would work and this is one of those "it depends". I'm assuming your PingIdentity STS is an "Identity Provider" (meaning that it authenticates users), so in general it would be the last STS in the chain.

Some questions you need to ask yourself for making a decision:

- How much would you need to transform the claims issued by Ping? How powerful of a claims transformation capability do you need? (ADFS has more powerful claims transformation capabilities than ACS)
- What protocols does Ping STS enable? (WS-Fed? SAMLP?: ADFS supports SAMLP, ACS not yet)
- Who owns this STS (you, a partner?) How much control you have on each?
- Which is the platform you are more comfortable managing? which one would you like to "leave alone" as much as possible?

Also, you marked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497838/pingidentity-federation-meta-data-export-for-acs-not-exporting-with-a-digital-s) as "answered" but it seems related to this one.

Comment: This may actually be the issue, I can obtain the PingIdentity STS FederationMetaData XML file, but when importing this it gives an error "Information cannot be loaded" or something similar, in which there's not a lot of information out there on the web about. This is a SAML export though... if ACS does not support this then that'd be exactly the reason. You've answered my question though in the sense that PingIdentity can couple to AD FS 2.0 and then this to my ACS... I guess it's the joys of using upcoming software that's still in labs.

Comment: I thought Ping supported WS-Federation too. ACS can do that (and that's what it uses for ADFS integration). But...I might be mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

PingFed supports WS-Federation for Passive Requester Profile (as well as SAML 1.0/1.1 and 2.0) OOTB as well as SAML 1.1 and 2.0 for Active Profile use cases (both as IDP and SP for Active and Passive). I believe ACS does not support SAML 2.0 for PRP but it does support WS-Federation. I think ACS does support SAML 2.0 *tokens* for Active Requester Profile only.

It shouldn't be that hard to swap out an IDP Endpoint in ACS but I've never looked at how that is accomplished.

HTH -- Ian

Comment: @thedixon - if you use WS-Federation on Ping, then you should be able to run this successfully. ACS supports SAML1.1 and 2.0 *tokens* in all profiles (together with "Simple Web Tokens").